# Multiple entities named the same interface as their proxy which is not supported

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am in the process of upgrading an applications tech stack and currently trying to upgrade from hibernate 4.3.11 to 5.4.23.

the system is outdated and still uses xml mapping - i have added the nomination xml file at the bottom

I have managed to complete most of the required changes going off guides/documentation but now when running the app, i get hit with this **runtime error**.

```
datasource-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Multiple entities [com.app.application.nomination.domain.AnnualNomination, com.app.application.nomination.domain.IntraDayNomination] named the same interface [com.app.application.nomination.domain.Nomination] as their proxy which is not supported
```

I am unsure about how to fix this and why it isnt allowed. If someone could share their knowledge then that would be very appreciated.

**tech stack**

- java 11
- spring 5
- hibernate 5

here is my datasource config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${datasource.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${datasource.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${datasource.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${datasource.password}"/>
        <property name="initialSize" value="${datasource.initialPoolSize}" />
        <property name="minIdle" value="${datasource.minPoolSize}" />
        <property name="maxIdle" value="${datasource.maxPoolSize}" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="${datasource.maxStatements}" />
        <property name="validationQuery" value="select 1 from dual"/>
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
        <property name="testOnReturn" value="false"/>
    </bean>
   
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:com/app/application/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.amor"/>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="persistenceContext" class="com.app.application.core.dao.hibernate.DefaultHibernatePersistenceContext">
        <constructor-arg ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    
</beans>
```

here is the nomination.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping default-access="field">
    <typedef name="NominationStatus" class="com..application.core.dao.hibernate.usertype.EnumUserType">
        <param name="enumClassName">com..application.nomination.domain.NominationStatus</param>
    </typedef>
    <typedef name="NominationType" class="com..application.core.dao.hibernate.usertype.EnumUserType">
        <param name="enumClassName">com..application.nomination.domain.NominationType</param>
    </typedef>
    <class table="NOMINATION" 
        name="com..application.nomination.domain.NominationImpl" 
        proxy="com..application.nomination.domain.Nomination" abstract="true" >
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="ID" precision="20" scale="0" />
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">NOMINATION_ID_SEQ</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <discriminator column="NOMINATION_TYPE" type="string" />
        <component name="nominationDetails" class="com..application.nomination.domain.NominationDetails">
            <property name="gasDay" type="LocalDate">
                <column name="GAS_DAY" not-null="true" />
            </property>
            <many-to-one name="flowpath" class="com..application.network.domain.FlowpathImpl">
                <column name="FLOWPATH_ID" not-null="true" />
            </many-to-one>
            <many-to-one name="shipper" class="com..application.network.domain.ShipperImpl">
                <column name="SHIPPER_ID" not-null="true" />
            </many-to-one>
            <property name="submittedDateTime" type="DateTime">
                <column name="SUBMITTED_DATE_TIME" not-null="true" />
            </property>
            <property name="effectiveDateTime" type="DateTime">
                <column name="EFFECTIVE_DATE_TIME" not-null="false" />
            </property>
             <property name="nominationStatus" type="NominationStatus" not-null="true">
                <column name="NOMINATION_STATUS" length="64" />
            </property>
            
            <property name="nominationType" type="NominationType" column="NOMINATION_TYPE" insert="false" update="false" />
            
            <property name="revisionNumber" type="int">
                <column name="REVISION_NUMBER" scale="0" not-null="true" />
            </property>
            <property name="superseded" type="yes_no">
                <column name="SUPERSEDED" length="1"/>
            </property>
            <property name="curtailed" type="yes_no">
                <column name="CURTAILED" length="1"/>
            </property>
            <many-to-one name="estimatedCondensate" class="com..application.data.domain.datapoint.EnergyDataValueImpl" fetch="select" cascade="all">
                <column name="ESTIMATED_CONDENSATE_ID" not-null="false" />  
            </many-to-one>
            <many-to-one name="deliveryRequirementVolume" class="com..application.data.domain.datapoint.VolumeDataValueImpl" fetch="select" cascade="all">
                <column name="DELIVERY_REQ_VOLUME_ID" not-null="false" />  
            </many-to-one>
            <many-to-one name="deliveryRequirementEnergy" class="com..application.data.domain.datapoint.EnergyDataValueImpl" fetch="select" cascade="all">
                <column name="DELIVERY_REQ_ENERGY_ID" not-null="false" />  
            </many-to-one>
            <many-to-one name="nominatedEnergy" class="com..application.data.domain.datapoint.EnergyDataValueImpl" fetch="select" cascade="all">
                <column name="NOMINATED_ENERGY_ID" not-null="false" />  
            </many-to-one>
            <many-to-one name="nominatedVolumeFirm" class="com..application.data.domain.datapoint.VolumeDataValueImpl" fetch="select" cascade="all">
                <column name="NOMINATED_VOLUME_FIRM_ID" not-null="false" />  
            </many-to-one>
            <many-to-one name="nominatedVolumeInterruptible" class="com..application.data.domain.datapoint.VolumeDataValueImpl" fetch="select" cascade="all">
                <column name="NOMINATED_VOLUME_INT_ID" not-null="false" />  
            </many-to-one>
            <many-to-one name="curtailedVolumeFirm" class="com..application.data.domain.datapoint.VolumeDataValueImpl" fetch="select" cascade="all">
                <column name="REVISED_VOLUME_FIRM_ID" not-null="false" />  
            </many-to-one>
            <many-to-one name="curtailedVolumeInterruptible" class="com..application.data.domain.datapoint.VolumeDataValueImpl" fetch="select" cascade="all">
                <column name="REVISED_VOLUME_INT_ID" not-null="false" />  
            </many-to-one>
            <many-to-one name="redeliveryRequirementEnergy" class="com..application.data.domain.datapoint.EnergyDataValueImpl" fetch="select" cascade="all">
                <column name="REDELIVERY_REQ_ENERGY_ID" not-null="true" />  
            </many-to-one>
            <many-to-one name="redeliveryRequirementVolume" class="com..application.data.domain.datapoint.VolumeDataValueImpl" fetch="select" cascade="all">
                <column name="REDELIVERY_REQ_VOLUME_ID" not-null="false" />  
            </many-to-one>
            <many-to-one name="redeliveryVolume" class="com..application.data.domain.datapoint.VolumeDataValueImpl" fetch="select" cascade="all">
                <column name="REDELIVERY_VOLUME_ID" not-null="false" />  
            </many-to-one>
            <many-to-one name="redeliveryEnergy" class="com..application.data.domain.datapoint.EnergyDataValueImpl" fetch="select" cascade="all">
                <column name="REDELIVERY_ENERGY_ID" not-null="false" />  
            </many-to-one>
            <property name="comment" type="java.lang.String">
                <column name="NOMINATION_COMMENT" length="3000" not-null="false" />
            </property>
            <property name="interimImbalance" type="RTNumber">
                <column name="INTERIM_IMBALANCE" not-null="false" />  
            </property>
            <property name="locked" type="yes_no">
                <column name="LOCKED" length="1"/>
            </property>
            <property name="confirmedByTransporter" type="yes_no">
                <column name="CONFIRMED_BY_TRANSPORTER" length="1"/>
            </property>
             <many-to-one name="systemUser" class="com..application.security.domain.NgcSystemUserImpl" fetch="select">
                <column name="SYSTEM_USER_ID" length="32" not-null="true" />
            </many-to-one>
        </component>
        
        <subclass discriminator-value="ANNUAL" 
            name="com..application.nomination.domain.AnnualNomination"
            proxy="com..application.nomination.domain.Nomination"
        />
        <subclass discriminator-value="MONTHLY" 
            name="com..application.nomination.domain.MonthlyNomination"
            proxy="com..application.nomination.domain.Nomination"
        />
        <subclass discriminator-value="DAILY" 
            name="com..application.nomination.domain.DailyNomination"
            proxy="com..application.nomination.domain.Nomination"
        />
        <subclass discriminator-value="INTRA_DAY" 
            name="com..application.nomination.domain.IntraDayNomination"
            proxy="com..application.nomination.domain.Nomination"
        />
        <subclass discriminator-value="DAILY_TRUE_UP" 
            name="com..application.nomination.domain.DailyTrueUpNomination"
            proxy="com..application.nomination.domain.Nomination"
        />
        <subclass discriminator-value="MONTHLY_TRUE_UP" 
            name="com..application.nomination.domain.MonthlyTrueUpNomination"
            proxy="com..application.nomination.domain.Nomination"
        />
       
    </class>
    <query name="findAnnualNominationsApplicableBetweenDates"><![CDATA[
        select n1 from AnnualNomination as n1  
        where n1.nominationDetails.effectiveDateTime 
        between (select max(n2.nominationDetails.effectiveDateTime) 
                 from AnnualNomination n2
                 where n2.nominationDetails.effectiveDateTime < :startDate) 
            and (select max(n3.nominationDetails.effectiveDateTime) 
                 from AnnualNomination n3
                 where n3.nominationDetails.effectiveDateTime < :endDate) 
    ]]></query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: 1. What does `com..application` mean? That's not a legal package name.

Comment: 2. Most likely, you can simply remove all the `proxy=...` attributes. I doubt you need them.

Comment: @GavinKing had to remove some of the package name for security reasons - also thank you, i will try doing this today.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to GavinKing for the answer in the comments. Removing the proxy property from my xml file solved this error.

```
    <subclass discriminator-value="MONTHLY_TRUE_UP" 
        name="com..application.nomination.domain.MonthlyTrueUpNomination"
        proxy="com..application.nomination.domain.Nomination"
    />
```